# Modifying stripe checkout form from one input contains all the required data to multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I enabled a payment using a credit card by stripe and was working fine, but it had only one input box requesting all info. I need to modify the form to show multiple inputs.
I did a new HTML form with 4 inputs and every input in a div with different id names.
What I understand from the stripe docs is to modify the javascript file with the new ids as the following:
**The old one:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="">  // Create a Stripe client.
  var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_XIkEi7uiUwtCIjdXShReMZ1e00kRB6lXjg');

  // Create an instance of Elements.
  var elements = stripe.elements();

  // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
  // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
  var style = {
    base: {
      color: '#32325d',
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      fontSize: '16px',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4'
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: '#fa755a',
      iconColor: '#fa755a'
    }
  };

  // Create an instance of the card Element.
  var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
  card.mount('#card-element');

  // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
  card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  // Handle form submission.
  var form = document.getElementById('stripe-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error.
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server.
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });
  });

  // Submit the form with the token ID.
  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('stripe-form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
  }
</script>
```

**The modified one:**

```js
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="">
    // Create a Stripe client.  
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_tes**************************');

    // Create an instance of Elements.   var elements =
    stripe.elements();

    // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
    // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide
    below.) var style = {
        base: {
            color: '#32325d',
            fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
            fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
            fontSize: '16px',
            '::placeholder': {
                color: '#aab7c4'
            }
        },
        invalid: {
            color: '#fa755a',
            iconColor: '#fa755a'
        }
    };

    // Create an instance of the card Element.   //var card =
    elements.create('card', {
        style: style
    });
    var cardNumberElement =
        elements.create('cardNumber');
    var cardExpiryElement =
        elements.create('cardExpiry');
    var cardCvcElement =
        elements.create('cardCvc');
    var zipCodeElement =
        elements.create('zipCode');


    // Add an instance of the card Element into the `stripe-form` <div>.
    cardNumberElement.mount('#cardNumber');
    cardExpiryElement.mount('#cardExpiry');
    cardCvcElement.mount('#cardCvc');
    zipCodeElement.mount('#zipCode');

    // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.  
    card.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
        var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        if (event.error) {
            displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
        } else {
            displayError.textContent = '';
        }
    });

    // Handle form submission.   var form =
    document.getElementById('stripe-form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        stripe.createToken(card).then(function (result) {
            if (result.error) {
                // Inform the user if there was an error.
                var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
            } else {
                // Send the token to your server.
                stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
            }
        });
    });

    // Submit the form with the token ID.   function
    stripeTokenHandler(token) {
        // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        var form = document.getElementById('stripe-form');
        var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
        form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
        ///
        var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');

        submitButton.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
            stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
                payment_method: {
                    card: card,
                    billing_details: {
                        name: 'Jenny Rosen'
                    }
                }
            }).then(function (result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    // Show error to your customer (e.g., insufficient funds)
                    console.log(result.error.message);
                } else {
                    // The payment has been processed!
                    if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
                        // Show a success message to your customer
                        // There's a risk of the customer closing the window before callback
                        // execution. Set up a webhook or plugin to listen for the
                        // payment_intent.succeeded event that handles any business critical
                        // post-payment actions.
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        // Submit the form
        form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

I want to know what's wrong with that since payment does work anymore after the .

modification

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "doesn't work anymore" means? Sharing an error message, stack trace, or anything along those lines would help to narrow down the root cause.

Comment: After updating the form, then changing the elements, it gives me "invalid parameters". The default form and javascript part were working fine.